# When searching for references to error correcting codes via pde

Tags: abstract-algebra, partial-differential-equations

Doing some research I didn't find any modeling of differential equations (elliptic, if possible) for error correcting codes. Do you know of any interesting references?

Note: I saw many approaches with algebra theory. However, I would like to know different approaches.